# Why do I get this error with Angular: "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' ..."?

Tags: angular, nestjs

I have this error message in the browser:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I know there are lot if similar questions but none of them really helped. I am using Angular with NestJS backend.

My Service file:

```
export class ApiService {
  url: string = "http://localhost:3000/api/user";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ///GET API
  getApi(): Observable<Api[]> {
    const url = `${this.url}`;
    return this.http.get<Api[]>(url, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

The component:

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  api: Api[];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getApi().subscribe(
      (user) => {
        this.api = user;
        console.log(this.api);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please add the html ? This error happens when you pass an object to an ngFor loop

Comment: The error indicates you are using ngfor to iterate over something that is not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of this line here:

```
this.apiService.getApi().subscribe(
      (user) => {
        this.api = user; // <-- this isn't an array
        console.log(this.api);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
```

The return of your `this.apiService.getApi` is returning a single object and not an array. `*ngFor` won't accept this.

The quickest way to fix it would simply be wrapping it, but I'm pretty confident that's not what your ultimate goal is:

```
this.apiService.getApi().subscribe(
      (user) => {
        this.api = [ user ]; // wrap it in an array
        console.log(this.api);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
```

Are you sure you are wanting to iterate on the object or maybe your node endpoint isn't returning the correct results? Are you trying to use `*ngFor` to iterate over the properties in the `user` object?

It might be helpful to post your node code if your endpoint isn't returning what you are expecting it to (since that's ultimately where the problem begins)

Remember, just because you are telling TypeScript *what type* something is, doesn't mean *it will actually be that type at runtime*

Comment: Yea, that's TypeScript letting you know that your Types are not correct. Make sure the entire flow is correct (either `Api` or `Api[]`)

Comment: Looks like youre models aren't matching. The error is telling you exactly which properties are missing. Validate that your types match up. It's hard to tell you the issue without seeing the full stacktrace and code. You originally question was answered here. Please mark as answer if you want any further assistance